# Python - special characters reading from URL parameter

Tags: python, django, url

I am reading URL parameter from the below URL

```
http://exaple.com/api/v1/get_example/?fruits_name=[apple%20+%20banana]

fruits = urllib.unquote(request.GET.get('fruits_name', None)).decode('utf8')
    print fruits
```

my output is: `[apple  banana]` in between apple and banana I am getting three spaces but not `+` symbol in my output. the original string is `[apple + banana]`. I need output as `[apple + banana]`.

Can anyone suggest where I am doing wrong??

Comment: Please share your full reproducable code with us so that we can reproduce your issue and get context for the problem.

Comment: @Jordan Singer  my urls.py file is

url(r'^api/v1/get_example/$', views.get_example,name='get_example'),

and views.py is 

@api_view(['GET'])
def get_example(request):
    fruits = urllib.unquote(request.GET.get('fruits_name', none)).decode('utf8')
    print fruits

Comment: Why do have the spaces quoted (%20) but not the plus sign (%2B) ? In a quoted URL, a plus sign is unquoted to a 'space', that's why you end up with 3 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use `%2B`

**Ex:**

```
http://exaple.com/api/v1/get_example/?fruits_name=[apple%20%2B%20banana]
```

**[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

You could split query string on your own to preserve the plus sign:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, unquote

u = 'http://exaple.com/api/v1/get_example/?fruits_name=[apple%20+%20banana]'

o = urlparse(u)
qs = unquote(o.query)

queryDict = {k: v for (k, v) in [x.split("=", 1) for x in qs.split("&")]}
print(queryDict)
```

Prints:

```
{'fruits_name': '[apple + banana]'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace special characters in string using the %xx escape. Letters, digits, and the characters '_.-' are never quoted. By default, this function is intended for quoting the path section of the URL.The optional safe parameter specifies additional characters that should not be quoted — its default value is '/'